# How to manually generate a TCP packet with python

Tags: python, tcp, packet, snort

I need to generate TCP packet with **ACK flag enabled** and **value 0**.

This is to test *Snort rules*:

`alert icmp any any -> any any (msg: "TCP PING DETECT"; flag: A; value: 0)`

I haven't found any solution for this yet.

Comment: That's going to be hard since the ACK flag is a TCP (not ICMP) feature. The rule seems to refer to some different than an ICMP echo request.

Comment: @Klaus D 
I made a mistake while writing. i fixed it xD xD

Comment: check out scapy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapy